# Using Ajax with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-analytics

I'm creating a site where the main content is changed by Ajax calls, and I want to add Google Analytics code (using the async _gaq method).
I understand I need to push a _trackPageview event with the URI to _gaq. There are 2 ways I can go about doing this:

1) Use an onclick property (or bind events with JQuery) on my links and forms, eg: onlink="_gaq.push(....)"

2) Since my ajax code can process scripts when receiving the data from the ajax request, I can add the _gaq.push(...) call in such a script snippet when providing the ajaxed page.

Using the first option, yields a cleaner and more concise code I guess. However, the drawbacks is that I have to remember to put in ALL links and forms the analytics code, and if I use it on a form with JS validation, the click gets analyzed by GA even if the validation fails.

The second option seems less clean, but solves the above issues. I can have one GA code which just checks if we are serving ajax or normal pages and output a JS snippet accordingly. Also, form submission get logged only when a form is really submitted.

I would appreciate any thoughts or comments on this. Perhaps there are more considerations, or ways to do this?

Thanks
Yaron

Answer (score 4):

There are some smarter ways to do it if you are using jQuery.

One possibility is to bind to the event [ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/)

```js
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, opt){
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', opt.url]);
});
```

Then from there on all jQuery ajax calls will trigger this event and it will push the url you requested via Ajax to `_gaq`.

Keep in mind that it will push the urls exactly how you requested it. So if you call:

```
$.ajax('http://www.mydomain.com/path')
```

`http://www.mydomain.com/path` will be pushed to the _gaq. Probably that's not what you want. So it's better to call `.ajax` like this:

```
$.ajax('/path');
```

Now that's only `/path` is pushed to _gaq.

If you really need to use the whole domain, than it's a good idea to sanitize the url before pushing it to Google Analytics.

Comment: Thanks Eduardo,

I like the idea, and need to consider it further. The only downside I can see, is that if some ajax calls are NOT meant to be sent to analytics I'd need some extra logic somewhere. But I guess that's doable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as a new answer since it's a different approach.

If you don't want to bind to the global event `ajaxSucess`, you can do it manually using deferreds.

```
$.ajax('/page').done(function(){
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/page']);
}).done(function(response){
  // Do something with the response
});
```

The bad thing is that the done callback don't receive the url. So You'll be typing the url twice. Since you're probably going to do it a couple of times, it may be handy to create a helper function:

```
function GaAjax(url){
  return (function(u){
    return $.ajax(u).done(function(){
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', u]);
    });
  })(url);
}
```

Now you can call that instead of the jQuery `.ajax` when you're doing an Ajax request that should be sent to Google Analytics.

```
GaAjax('/page').done(function(){
  // Do something with the response
});
```